# Find out the number of processes

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe, fork

I have a simple **pipe** program which creates child processes in order to write some info and the parent process will display this info.

```
int main() {
   int pfd[2], i, n;
   pipe(pfd);
   for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
     if(fork() == 0) {
        write(pfd[1], &i, sizeof(int));
        close(pfd[0]); close(pfd[1]);
        exit(0);
     }
     else {

     }
   }
   for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
      wait(0);
      read(pfd[0], &n, sizeof(int));
      printf("%d\n", n);
   }
   close(pfd[0]); close(pfd[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

In this situation parent process will receive follow results : `0 ,1 and 2`.

If I delete the line which contains `exit(0)` how can I find out the number of processes created by the program ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The number of processes created is equal to the number of calls to `fork()`.  If you delete the `exit(0)` calls, the children will attempt to continue through the loop (`fork()`ing again) and then they will `wait(0)`.  They'll get resulting `ECHILD` from some of their `wait()`s.  Is this really what you intend or do you mean something else?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working example that tracks the count of children created.  Note that `fork()` will create another address space that won't allow you to share variables among parent/child.  But the program counter will remain the same and so parent and child will pick up executing right after the call to `fork()`.

If you do a `fork()` in a loop, your child will get to the end of the body, if it passes the condition it will execute the body (including the `fork()` again).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main() {
   int pfd[2], i, n;
   pid_t children_pids[3];
   int children_created = 0;
   memset(children_pids, 0, sizeof(children_pids));

   pipe(pfd);
   for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
     pid_t p = fork();
     if(p == 0) {
        write(pfd[1], &i, sizeof(int));
        close(pfd[0]); close(pfd[1]);
        exit(0);
//      break;
     }
     else {
        children_pids[children_created++] = p;
     }
   }
   for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
      pid_t p = waitpid(children_pids[i], NULL, 0);
      if (p == -1) {
          /* error, but expected w/o exit() above */ 
          continue;
      }
      read(pfd[0], &n, sizeof(int));
      printf("%d\n", n);
   }
   close(pfd[0]); close(pfd[1]);

   printf("Total children: %d\n", children_created);
   return 0;
}
```